# invalid sql Group By Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables by the following data :

Table 1 (`MOF_Check_Vendor`)

```
id  ApprovalCycel_ID    FPM_Vendor_ID   BankAccount_ID
------------------------------------------------------
13  23                       197          11
14  24                       198          6
22  25                       198          6
```

Table 2 (`ApprovalCycel`)

```
ApprovalCycel_ID    Currency_id fpm_vendor_id   Invoice_Number
--------------------------------------------------------------
23                       133    197              INV02
24                       133    198              INV03
25                       133    198              BOInvoice
```

I use this query to get the wanted result :

```
SELECT 
   FPM_Vendor_ID,
   STUFF(
          (SELECT 
              'Invoice_Number' + char(9) + 
              'InvoiceCurrency' + char(9) + 
              'Amount' + char(13) + char(10) +
              CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ap.Invoice_Number) + char(9) +
              CUR + char(9) +
              CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ap.Ammount) + char(13) + char(10)
           FROM 
              dbo.ApprovalCycel ap
           JOIN 
              dbo.Country ON ap.Currency_id = dbo.Country.Country_ID
           LEFT JOIN 
              dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor mv ON ap.ApprovalCycel_ID = mv.ApprovalCycel_ID
           WHERE 
              mv.ID IN (13,14,22)
           GROUP BY 
              PR_Request_Supplier_ID, Invoice_Number, CUR, Amount
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '') AS GComment
FROM 
   dbo.ApprovalCycel 
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor ON dbo.ApprovalCycel.ApprovalCycel_ID = dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor.ApprovalCycel_ID
WHERE 
   ID IN (13, 14, 22)
GROUP BY 
   FPM_Vendor_ID, BankAccount_ID
```

The result is returned like this:

```
FPM_Vendor_ID    GComment
------------------------------------------------------------
    197          Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV02 QAR 500.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; BOInvoice QAR 1000.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV03 QAR 1000.00&#x0D; 
    198          Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV02 QAR 500.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; BOInvoice QAR 1000.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV03 QAR 1000.00&#x0D;
```

But it should be:

```
FPM_Vendor_ID   GComment
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    197         Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV02 QAR        500.00&#x0D; 
    198         Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; BOInvoice QAR 1000.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV03 QAR 1000.00&#x0D;
```

I need the result to be as follows:

```
FPM_Vendor_ID   GComment
------------------------------------------------------------
   197          Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV02 QAR 500.00&#x0D;  
   198          Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; BOInvoice QAR 1000.00&#x0D; Invoice_Number InvoiceCurrency Amout&#x0D; INV03 QAR 1000.00&#x0D;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do and what is wrong with your current results?  This is very hard to follow...

Comment: You're trying to build your own result set using tabs and linefeeds? Wouldn't it be easier to just use columns and rows...

Comment: the result display that the two result lines show the same results , but the real and the should be every vendor should have only its own invoice NO.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all but i'm seolved this problem
by changing the query as below :

```
SELECT FPM_Vendor_ID,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT 'Invoice_Number' + char(9) + 'InvoiceCurrency' + char(9) + 
                'Amount' + char(13) + char(10) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 
                ap.Invoice_Number) + char(9) + CUR + char(9) + 
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ap.Ammount) + char(13) + char(10)
                FROM dbo.ApprovalCycel ap
                JOIN dbo.Country ON ap.Currency_id = dbo.Country.Country_ID
                LEFT JOIN dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor mv ON ap.ApprovalCycel_ID = mv.ApprovalCycel_ID
                WHERE mv.FPM_Vendor_ID = MOF_Check_Vendor.FPM_Vendor_ID
                GROUP BY PR_Request_Supplier_ID, Invoice_Number, CUR, Amount
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '') AS GComment
FROM dbo.ApprovalCycel
LEFT JOIN dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor ON dbo.ApprovalCycel.ApprovalCycel_ID = dbo.MOF_Check_Vendor.ApprovalCycel_ID
WHERE ID IN (13,14,22)
GROUP BY FPM_Vendor_ID, BankAccount_ID
```